# simplify the equation $\frac{36}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{9}{\sqrt{y}} = 42-9\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$

Tags: radical-equations

This is the question:

$$\frac{36}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{9}{\sqrt{y}} = 42-9\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}$$

This is from a timed competition, and I would like to know the fastest way to do it. I'm not sure, but is there a faster way than to replace $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ with other variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite: $$\Big(\frac{36}{\sqrt{x}} + 9\sqrt{x}\Big)+\Big(\frac{9}{\sqrt{y}}+\sqrt{y}\Big)=42$$

Now by Am-Gm inequality ($a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$) we have $$\frac{36}{\sqrt{x}} + 9\sqrt{x}\geq 36$$ and $$\frac{9}{\sqrt{y}} +\sqrt{y}\geq  6$$

So we must have equality case. Thus $x =4$ and $y= 9$.